# What is the dif between @ID annotaion in JPA and Hbernate? is there any difference?

Tags: hibernate

i m new to hibernate,as we know jpa is just specification for hibernate but in entity class we use @id annotations from javax.persistence package to declare id as a primary key, is that id belongs to hibernate by using it. where i can find the difference between them in practically.

Answer (score 1):

All that @Id is from javax.persistence which means it comes from JPA. 
You can think of JPA as abstract class and hibernate is the implementation.

Since Hibernate also using this annotation without creating another annotation with the same name(like @Entity and @Table which both hibernate and JPA have) the main purpose is intended to be the same as JPA standard. As for the annotation that defined in both hibernate and JPA, you can see the description on each of it's javadoc.

Answer (score -1):

As we can read [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_annotations.htm), in hibernate

> Each entity bean will have a primary key, which you annotate on the
>   class with the @Id annotation. The primary key can be a single field
>   or a combination of multiple fields depending on your table structure.

and, [here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id), in JPA

> The @Id annotation marks a field as a primary key field. When a
>   primary key field is defined the primary key value is automatically
>   injected into that field by ObjectDB.

So I guess the difference is that in JPA @Id might be used in a combanation of fields